# What is the best practice OR right way to reference class defined variables from within the class functions?

Tags: software-design

Let's say we have a class with 3 class variables and function `funA` which calls another `funB`, while `funB` uses all 3 class declared variables.
So my question is should the `funB` reference variables from it's body, like this (pseudo-code):

```
class A{

   var var1 = ...
   var var2 = ...
   var var3 = ...

   funA(){
     funB()
   }

   funB(){
      // lets say we just multiply the values and store a result somewhere
      var result = var1 * var2 * var3
      ...
   }
}
```

or like this:

```
class A{

   var var1 = ...
   var var2 = ...
   var var3 = ...

   funA(){
     funB(var1, var2, var3)
   }

   funB(var1, var2, var3){
      // lets say we just multiply the values and store a result somewhere
      var result = var1 * var2 * var3
      ...
   }
}
```

What is the best practice? Is it dependent on the language?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to be an opinion-based question with a universal answer: _it depends_.  `funB()` without args is better if you need to hide its implementation within class A.  `funB(arg1, arg2, arg3)` does not depend on the state of class A being pure function; it may be altogether removed from `A` to some utility/helper class.

Comment: It's not so much about the language as it is about good object-oriented design - specifically, encapsulation.  If var1, var2, and var3 are properties of a particular class, don't expose them to the outside world unnecessarily.  Allow the class to manage its own internal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second way is no added value, i would prefer the first way.